# Is it possible for people over 25 years old to to grow taller?

Tags: physiology

Human height growth tends to saturate at age of 15 in females and 18-20 in males. But, many claim (i.e. "[How to increase your height with easy exercises](http://www.squidoo.com/How-To-Increase-Your-Height-With-Easy-Exercises)") that it is possible to increase your height even after the those ages, and even beyond 25.

The claims are made on the basis of stretching and their straightening the spine, for a modest (less than 2 inch) difference. Many studies refer to the "cobra stretch", "cat stretch", one leg straight up and other straightening exercises.

Is this true? Does a 25-year-old doing such exercises on regular basis have any chance of increasing their height?

Comment: Just to be sure: I assume you are asking if it is possible to increase height permanently? Most people increase their height each day, by means of sleeping.

Comment: Yes , i was asking about permanently. BTW that's an interesting thing you made out about temporary increase while sleeping, i am not much aware about that

Comment: Your spine has a natural curve.  There are ways to straighten it out, which would yield a slightly taller stature, however the curve is there in order to distribute the weight of the upper body evenly throughout the spin and transmit it to the hips. Removing those curves not only decreases flexibility, but would result in poor weight distribution along the spine, increasing the risk of injury and deterioration.

Comment: @Adam : that's a very good comment. Other than answering the question, you also cleared the side-effects too. Thanks mate !!

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know, [human growth is an hormonal regulated process](http://www.hypertropin.com/howhghworks.html). So taking some hormons would allow one to grow "forever". Actualy, [Robert Wadlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Wadlow) [the tallest man in guiness records](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/records-3000/tallest-man-ever/) was a man who continued growth in adulthood were due to hyperplasia of his pituitary gland, which results in an abnormally high level of human growth hormone.

Also, [stretching](http://www.livestrong.com/article/431962-does-stretching-cause-damage/) may lead [to damages](http://www.endalldisease.com/the-myth-of-stretching-for-flexibility-and-the-damage-it-causes/),  be careful that here too you should respect your body and its limits.

Comment: Please do reference your answers. They provide little value otherwise.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Livestrong have proven to be an unreliable source of scientific information. It would be better to read and quote their sources directly, rather than rely on than them.

Comment: So barring cases like Robert Wadlow, who clearly had some abnormal physiology going on, this answer doesn't take into account the normal process of stopping height.  Once the epiphyseal plate becomes the epiphyseal line in most adults, HGH or other techniques won't serve to make that person taller, just larger.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphyseal_plate.  This process also helps to explain why women tend to be shorter than men; the release of estrogen causes this transformation, and women, with more estrogen earlier (generally), stop growth faster.